# I roll a die $N$ times, what is the probability that the sum is exactly $k$?

Tags: probability, dice, binomial-distribution

The die is six-sided. So, this is easy with a two-sided coin showing exactly $k$ heads, as that is just a Bernoulli trial being run $n$ times (Binomial RV).

You can also approximate this using a normal random variable with $N(3.5\times n, \frac{35}{12} \times n)$. But that doesn't yield an exact answer for $k$. I can get an answer for the value being $at\ least\ k$, that is easy. In fact, as $n$ approaches infinity, [we know it will in fact be a normal distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406192/probability-distribution-of-rolling-multiple-dice).

I can also run a simulation that will get me to a close value for a given $n$ and $k$.

But how do I figure out the exact value? This is not a continuous distribution, this is discrete. i.e. what is the generalized formula for this? There are many posts online that show all the previously mentioned methods, I couldn't find anything for a generalized version of the exact solution to this problem, however.

Comment: You can find a thorough explanation and formula in [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992125/rolling-dice-problem/1680420#1680420)