# Formula for the probability of rolling the most probable sum of n s-sided dice

Tags: probability, dice

The most likely sum of any roll of *n* unbiased *s*-sided dice is given by:

$ P (n, s) = \frac{1}{2} n ( s + 1 )$

This tells us, of course, that for an odd number *n*, the most likely sum will be fractional; that is, two sums will be equally likely.

Is there a simple, closed formula that would determine the probability of that most likely sum? It strikes me that such a formula should exist, since any particular sum has a definite and predictable number of summands, based upon $n$ and $s$. And since the total number of permutations is $s^n$, the question becomes one of calculating the number of ways the most likely number can be achieved with those dice.

Thank you.

Comment: By generating functions, the coefficient of $x^{\frac{n(s+1)}{2}}$ in the expansion of $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^s)^n/s^n$.  Simplifying this monstrosity however is easier said than done.

Comment: That said, it should be relatively easy to approximate.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397689/why-convolution-regularize-functions/398146#398146) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406192/probability-distribution-of-rolling-multiple-dice) for instance.  You'll find that as the number of dice grows the curve smooths out and approaches the normal curve.