# Approximating a Multivariable Piecewise Function to a smooth continuous Multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I want to know how to approximate a general multivariable linear piecewise function (in both cases where it's continious but not smooth and when it's not continious nor smooth) $\mathbb{R}^{n} 
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to a smooth continuous multivariable function $\mathbb{R}^{n} 
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2015/376362/

I found this paper but I am not sure if the method presented works for $n>1$

Answer (score 0):

You can use a convolution with a smooth function. My experience is that it's good to consider $f*g_\varepsilon$, where $g_\varepsilon(x)=g(x/\varepsilon)/\varepsilon^n$ and $g$ is a function with the following properties

- $g(x)=0$ outside the unit ball
- $g(x)\geq 0$ (this is not crucial)
- $g$ is smooth
- $\int_{\Bbb R^n} g(x)dx=1$

This is a random [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397689/why-convolution-regularize-functions) about it that I found on MSE.

Comment: I'm guessing here x is a representation of more than 1 variable since we are in $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ ? and $\int_{\Bbb R^n} g(x)dx=1$ is the integral over the entire $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ domain?

Comment: The answer is 'yes' to both your questions.